# Hibernate Session vs Transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm a bit confused about the concept of Sessions and Transactions in Hibernate.
As far as i understand, Hibernate uses Sessions (Persistence Context), which is basically a Cache for Entitys that need to be persist, deleted or whatever in the Database.
Sessions encapsulate Transactions, so i start a Session, followed by creating a Transaction. After the Transaction is closed, everything from the Persistence Context is flushed to the Database.The same thing will happen, if i close the Session.

Why do i need both? Can i do the same without creating a Transaction?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can open more than 1 transaction within the same session.

Now, flushing doesn't necessarily relate to transaction commit. When you `save()` an entity - it'll be flushed if you use Identity generation strategy. When you `select` something - Session will also flush (if flush mode is AUTO). And you can even tell Hibernate not to flush before transaction commits (flush mode MANUAL).

Transactions are only responsible for ACID, it's a DB feature. While Session is responsible for managing entities, generating SQL, handling events. It's a Java thing.

PS: Session isn't just a "cache". It's also a way to track which entities are changed. So it's more than just an optimization trick.

Comment: So transactions are mandatory and used to ensure that all- or none of the encapsulated operations are performed, else it will all be rolled back, right? And the session keeps track of all entitys i fetched from the database or needs to be changed, until they are flushed?

Comment: Yep, something like that

Comment: That's correct, except that transactions are not mandatory. But, if in doubt, it's usually better to do something in a transaction